# Add the same file on all branches of a repository

Tags: git

My git repository has four branches: master, bch1, bch2, and bch3. Now I want to add a same file `test` on each branch. How do I do this?

Comment: Is your repository already tracking `test`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the file in one branch, and then if it fits your merge strategy, merge that into your other branches (pick the first branch so this works).

Alternatively, add the file in one branch and commit, then `git cherry-pick` the commit.